# Activity set in AndroidManifest is not getting called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-manifest

I am new to android and have just made a simple login app using Firebase. The problem is that, I first developed the registration page and then the login page.

Now when i am specifying my `LoginActivity` in the `AndroidManifest` it is still calling the `RegisterActivity`.

I tried invalidating the caches, restarted but nothing is working it is still calling the `RegisterActivity` rather than `LoginActivity`

`AndroidManifiest` file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   <activity android:name=".RegisterStudent"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ResetPassword"></activity>
</application>
```

`LoginActivity` file:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button  btnReset;
    private TextView  btnLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
.....
```

`RegisterActivity` file:

```
public class RegisterStudent extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextInputLayout etStudentName, etStudentEmail, etPassword, etStudentPhone, etFeesPaid, etTotalfees;
    private AppCompatSpinner batchesSpinner;
    private Button registerStudentBtn;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_student);
.....
```

Log Cat:

```
01-07 01:47:49.582 16643-16643/? I/m.hitech.hitec: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-07 01:47:49.629 16643-16657/com.hitech.hitech I/m.hitech.hitec: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
01-07 01:47:49.771 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech W/m.hitech.hitec: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
01-07 01:47:49.773 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech I/chatty: uid=10187(com.hitech.hitech) identical 10 lines
01-07 01:47:49.773 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech W/m.hitech.hitec: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
01-07 01:47:49.780 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
01-07 01:47:49.803 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech W/m.hitech.hitec: Unsupported class loader
01-07 01:47:49.804 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech W/m.hitech.hitec: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
01-07 01:47:49.807 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
01-07 01:47:49.810 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
01-07 01:47:49.817 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] No Fallback module; NOT setting up for lazy initialization
01-07 01:47:49.823 16643-16660/com.hitech.hitech W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
01-07 01:47:49.827 16643-16660/com.hitech.hitech I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
01-07 01:47:49.828 16643-16660/com.hitech.hitech I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
01-07 01:47:49.841 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( mfjhDZacBWgG3rjpPB7ZKkTPJQd2 ).
01-07 01:47:49.846 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
01-07 01:47:49.880 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: 915335141
01-07 01:47:49.883 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
01-07 01:47:49.884 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
01-07 01:47:49.885 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
01-07 01:47:49.890 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech V/Font: Change font:2
01-07 01:47:49.897 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: Collection enabled
01-07 01:47:49.897 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: App package, google app id: com.hitech.hitech, 1:432442387783:android:03d10637e6d05449
01-07 01:47:49.898 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11717
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.hitech.hitech
01-07 01:47:49.898 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
01-07 01:47:49.902 16643-16666/com.hitech.hitech E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.profiler"
01-07 01:47:49.903 16643-16666/com.hitech.hitech E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
01-07 01:47:49.909 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: Connecting to remote service
01-07 01:47:49.914 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
01-07 01:47:49.941 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: onActivityCreated
01-07 01:47:49.968 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech W/m.hitech.hitec: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
01-07 01:47:49.969 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech W/m.hitech.hitec: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
01-07 01:47:50.063 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
    Notified 0 auth state listeners.
01-07 01:47:50.074 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@ca54cf0
01-07 01:47:50.084 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: onActivityCreated
01-07 01:47:50.200 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
01-07 01:47:50.201 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 730786762
01-07 01:47:50.201 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
01-07 01:47:50.202 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
01-07 01:47:50.203 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=RegisterStudent, firebase_screen_id(_si)=9094250577024489675}]
01-07 01:47:50.219 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
01-07 01:47:50.219 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech D/FA: Connected to remote service
01-07 01:47:50.219 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
01-07 01:47:50.273 16643-16657/com.hitech.hitech D/DecorView: onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@182005e[RegisterStudent]
01-07 01:47:50.274 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 0bf40b0, I486bafd568
    Build Date                       : 08/22/18
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.00
    Local Branch                     : 
    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.7.3.R1.08.00.00.423.039
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
    Build Config                     : S P 6.0.3 AArch64
01-07 01:47:50.276 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
01-07 01:47:50.277 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.graphics.memory"
    Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
    Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
01-07 01:47:50.278 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech I/Adreno: PFP: 0x016ee170, ME: 0x00000000
01-07 01:47:50.278 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
01-07 01:47:50.280 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 1
    android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
01-07 01:47:50.281 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-07 01:47:50.281 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
01-07 01:47:50.285 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.changepixelformat"
01-07 01:47:50.334 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
01-07 01:47:50.355 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
01-07 01:47:51.845 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
01-07 01:47:51.830 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:6573004): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=16956 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c187,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
01-07 01:47:51.850 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:6573005): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=16956 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c187,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
01-07 01:47:51.858 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
01-07 01:47:51.860 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:6573006): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=16956 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c187,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
01-07 01:47:51.874 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
01-07 01:47:51.880 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:6573007): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=16956 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c187,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
01-07 01:47:51.891 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
01-07 01:47:51.900 16643-16643/com.hitech.hitech W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:6573008): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=16956 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c187,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
01-07 01:47:51.907 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
01-07 01:47:51.992 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech I/chatty: uid=10187(com.hitech.hitech) RenderThread identical 5 lines
01-07 01:47:52.007 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
01-07 01:47:52.024 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
01-07 01:47:52.090 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech I/chatty: uid=10187(com.hitech.hitech) RenderThread identical 4 lines
01-07 01:47:52.107 16643-16670/com.hitech.hitech E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
01-07 01:47:55.252 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
01-07 01:48:19.541 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 29340
01-07 01:48:19.542 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: Connecting to remote service
01-07 01:48:19.545 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: Activity paused, time: 730816101
01-07 01:48:19.547 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=29340, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=RegisterStudent, firebase_screen_id(_si)=9094250577024489675}]
01-07 01:48:19.582 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
01-07 01:48:19.582 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech D/FA: Connected to remote service
01-07 01:48:19.582 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
01-07 01:48:24.607 16643-16663/com.hitech.hitech V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
01-07 01:48:29.633 16643-16660/com.hitech.hitech I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
    [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
```

Comment: Make sure you are not calling Registration Activity in the onCreate() function of your login activity. Your Manifest file seems okay. Will be more clearer if you post the complete code of your LoginActivity

Comment: I have uploaded the start of my LoginActivity wherr the setContentView is activity_login